# Json to Csv Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

i tried to convert and treat my json file with matchs and statistique to csv on spark but i have a recurrent problem :

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: [UNRESOLVED_COLUMN.WITH_SUGGESTION] A column or function parameter with name `team_names` cannot be resolved. Did you mean one of the following? [`data`, `meta`].;
> [error] 'Filter array_contains(split('team_names, ,, -1), data#56.team.full_name)

```
 import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
    import scala.io.Source
    import org.json4s._
    import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
    import org.json4s.DefaultFormats
    
    object Transform {
      def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val spark = SparkSession.builder()
          .appName("NBA_ETL")
          .master("local[*]")
          .getOrCreate()
    
        // Chemin d'entrée pour les fichiers JSON des matchs et des statistiques
        val matchsPaths = Seq(
          "/home/ubuntu/FirstProject/NBA_ETL/Atlanta Hawks-matches.json",
          "/home/ubuntu/FirstProject/NBA_ETL/Los Angeles Clippers-matches.json",
          "/home/ubuntu/FirstProject/NBA_ETL/Milwaukee Bucks-matches.json",
          "/home/ubuntu/FirstProject/NBA_ETL/Phoenix Suns-matches.json"
        )
    
        val statsPaths = Seq(
          "/home/ubuntu/FirstProject/NBA_ETL/Atlanta Hawks-stats.json",
          "/home/ubuntu/FirstProject/NBA_ETL/Los Angeles Clippers-stats.json",
          "/home/ubuntu/FirstProject/NBA_ETL/Milwaukee Bucks-stats.json",
          "/home/ubuntu/FirstProject/NBA_ETL/Phoenix Suns-stats.json"
        )
    
        // Lecture des fichiers JSON dans des DataFrames
        val matchsDFs = matchsPaths.map(path => spark.read.json(path))
        val statsDFs = statsPaths.map(path => spark.read.json(path))
    
        // Fusion des DataFrames des matchs
        val matchsTransformedDF = matchsDFs.reduce(_.union(_)).select(
          col("data.id").as("match_id"),
          col("data.home_team.full_name").as("home_team_name"),
          col("data.home_team.id").as("home_team_id"),
          col("data.home_team_score").as("home_team_score"),
          col("data.visitor_team.full_name").as("visitor_team_name"),
          col("data.visitor_team.id").as("visitor_team_id"),
          col("data.visitor_team_score").as("visitor_team_score")
        )
    
        // Fusion des DataFrames des statistiques
        val teamNames = Array("Phoenix Suns", "Atlanta Hawks", "Los Angeles Clippers", "Milwaukee Bucks")
        val teamNamesColumn = lit(teamNames.mkString(",")).as("team_names")
        val statsTransformedDF = statsDFs.reduce(_.union(_)).filter(array_contains(split(col("team_names"), ","), col("data.team.full_name")))
    
    
    
          .select(
            col("data.game.id").as("match_id"),
            col("data.team.full_name").as("team_name"),
            col("data.pts").as("points"),
            col("data.ast").as("assists"),
            col("data.blk").as("blocks"),
            col("data.dreb").as("defensive_rebounds"),
            col("data.fg3_pct").as("three_point_pct"),
            col("data.fg3a").as("three_point_attempts"),
            col("data.fg3m").as("three_point_made"),
            col("data.fg_pct").as("field_goal_pct"),
            col("data.fga").as("field_goal_attempts"),
            col("data.fgm").as("field_goals_made"),
            col("data.ft_pct").as("free_throw_pct"),
            col("data.fta").as("free_throw_attempts"),
            col("data.ftm").as("free_throws_made"),
            col("data.min").as("minutes"),
            col("data.oreb").as("offensive_rebounds"),
            col("data.pf").as("personal_fouls"),
            col("data.reb").as("rebounds"),
            col("data.stl").as("steals"),
            col("data.turnover").as("turnovers")
          )
    
        // Fusion des DataFrames
        val finalDF = matchsTransformedDF.join(statsTransformedDF, Seq("match_id"), "inner")
    
        // Chemin de sortie pour le fichier CSV final
        val outputPath = "..."
    
        // Sauvegarde du DataFrame final au format CSV
        finalDF.write.csv(outputPath)
    
        spark.stop()
      }
    }
```

thanks you for your help

```
    23/05/22 00:08:43 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Killing all running tasks in stage 7: Stage finished
23/05/22 00:08:43 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 7 finished: json at Transform.scala:32, took 0.077743 s
[error] org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: [UNRESOLVED_COLUMN.WITH_SUGGESTION] A column or function parameter with name `team_names` cannot be resolved. Did you mean one of the following? [`data`, `meta`].;
[error] 'Filter array_contains(split('team_names, ,, -1), data#56.team.full_name)
[error] +- Union false, false
[error]    :- Relation [data#56,meta#57] json
[error]    :- Relation [data#68,meta#69] json
[error]    :- Relation [data#80,meta#81] json
[error]    +- Relation [data#92,meta#93] json
[error] 
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryCompilationErrors$.unresolvedAttributeError(QueryCompilationErrors.scala:221)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$CheckAnalysis$$failUnresolvedAttribute(CheckAnalysis.scala:143)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.$anonfun$checkAnalysis0$5(CheckAnalysis.scala:258)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.$anonfun$checkAnalysis0$5$adapted(CheckAnalysis.scala:256)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:295)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$foreachUp$1(TreeNode.scala:294)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$foreachUp$1$adapted(TreeNode.scala:294)
[error]         at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
[error]         at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
[error]         at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
[error]         at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
[error]         at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)
[error]         at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:294)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$foreachUp$1(TreeNode.scala:294)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$foreachUp$1$adapted(TreeNode.scala:294)
[error]         at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
[error]         at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
[error]         at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
[error]         at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
[error]         at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)
[error]         at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:294)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.$anonfun$checkAnalysis0$4(CheckAnalysis.scala:256)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.$anonfun$checkAnalysis0$4$adapted(CheckAnalysis.scala:256)
[error]         at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.foreach(Stream.scala:533)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.$anonfun$checkAnalysis0$1(CheckAnalysis.scala:256)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.$anonfun$checkAnalysis0$1$adapted(CheckAnalysis.scala:163)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:295)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.checkAnalysis0(CheckAnalysis.scala:163)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.checkAnalysis0$(CheckAnalysis.scala:160)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.checkAnalysis0(Analyzer.scala:188)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.checkAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:156)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.checkAnalysis$(CheckAnalysis.scala:146)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.checkAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:188)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1(Analyzer.scala:211)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.markInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:330)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:208)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$analyzed$1(QueryExecution.scala:76)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:111)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$2(QueryExecution.scala:202)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.withInternalError(QueryExecution.scala:526)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$1(QueryExecution.scala:202)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:827)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executePhase(QueryExecution.scala:201)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:76)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:74)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:66)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:205)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:211)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.apply(Dataset.scala:75)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withTypedPlan(Dataset.scala:4201)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.filter(Dataset.scala:1712)
[error]         at Transform$.main(Transform.scala:48)
[error]         at Transform.main(Transform.scala)
[error]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[error]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[error]         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run last Compile / run for the full output
[error] (Compile / run) org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: [UNRESOLVED_COLUMN.WITH_SUGGESTION] A column or function parameter with name `team_names` cannot be resolved. Did you mean one of the following? [`data`, `meta`].;
[error] 'Filter array_contains(split('team_names, ,, -1), data#56.team.full_name)
[error] +- Union false, false
[error]    :- Relation [data#56,meta#57] json
[error]    :- Relation [data#68,meta#69] json
[error]    :- Relation [data#80,meta#81] json
[error]    +- Relation [data#92,meta#93] json
[error] Total time: 21 s, completed May 22, 2023, 12:08:43 AM
23/05/22 00:08:44 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
23/05/22 00:08:44 INFO SparkContext: SparkContext is stopping with exitCode 0.
23/05/22 00:08:44 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://ip-172-31-3-159.eu-west-1.compute.internal:4040
23/05/22 00:08:44 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
23/05/22 00:08:44 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
23/05/22 00:08:44 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
23/05/22 00:08:44 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
23/05/22 00:08:44 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
23/05/22 00:08:44 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
23/05/22 00:08:44 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
23/05/22 00:08:44 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-0826f37d-223e-4918-9742-65d77918bc3c
23/05/22 00:08:44 ERROR Configuration: error parsing conf core-default.xml
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/ubuntu/FirstProject/NBA_ETL/target/bg-jobs/sbt_75af393e/target/21c7a1d8/359669fc/hadoop-client-api-3.3.4.jar
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:55)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:149)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(LinuxFileSystemProvider.java:99)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1764)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1259)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:831)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource$FinalizableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:857)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:846)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:248)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:177)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:350)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:103)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:72)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:99)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:125)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(JarURLConnection.java:155)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.parse(Configuration.java:3009)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getStreamReader(Configuration.java:3105)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:3063)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResources(Configuration.java:3036)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadProps(Configuration.java:2914)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProps(Configuration.java:2896)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.get(Configuration.java:1246)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTimeDuration(Configuration.java:1863)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTimeDuration(Configuration.java:1840)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.getShutdownTimeout(ShutdownHookManager.java:183)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.shutdownExecutor(ShutdownHookManager.java:145)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.access$300(ShutdownHookManager.java:65)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run(ShutdownHookManager.java:102)
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/ubuntu/FirstProject/NBA_ETL/target/bg-jobs/sbt_75af393e/target/21c7a1d8/359669fc/hadoop-client-api-3.3.4.jar
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:3089)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResources(Configuration.java:3036)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadProps(Configuration.java:2914)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProps(Configuration.java:2896)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.get(Configuration.java:1246)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTimeDuration(Configuration.java:1863)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTimeDuration(Configuration.java:1840)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.getShutdownTimeout(ShutdownHookManager.java:183)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.shutdownExecutor(ShutdownHookManager.java:145)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.access$300(ShutdownHookManager.java:65)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run(ShutdownHookManager.java:102)
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/ubuntu/FirstProject/NBA_ETL/target/bg-jobs/sbt_75af393e/target/21c7a1d8/359669fc/hadoop-client-api-3.3.4.jar
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:55)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:149)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(LinuxFileSystemProvider.java:99)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1764)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1259)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:831)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource$FinalizableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:857)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:846)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:248)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:177)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:350)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:103)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:72)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:99)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:125)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(JarURLConnection.java:155)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.parse(Configuration.java:3009)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getStreamReader(Configuration.java:3105)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:3063)
        ... 10 more
```

I have scraping two different type of informations on https://app.balldontlie.io/#introduction (statistics and matchs for four teams)
I share an extract from json files :
statistics :

```
{"data":[{"id":7065956,"ast":4,"blk":0,"dreb":7,"fg3_pct":16.7,"fg3a":6,"fg3m":1,"fg_pct":36.4,"fga":11,"fgm":4,"ft_pct":60.0,"fta":5,"ftm":3,"game":{"id":455103,"date":"2021-08-10T00:00:00.000Z","home_team_id":11,"home_team_score":111,"period":0,"postseason":false,"season":2021,"status":"Final","time":"","visitor_team_id":9,"visitor_team_score":91},"min":"30:19","oreb":0,"pf":3,"player":{"id":3547256,"first_name":"Saddiq","height_feet":null,"height_inches":null,"last_name":"Bey","position":"F","team_id":1,"weight_pounds":null},"pts":12,"reb":7,"stl":0,"team":{"id":9,"abbreviation":"DET","city":"Detroit","conference":"East","division":"Central","full_name":"Detroit Pistons","name":"Pistons"},"turnover":3},{"id":7065957,"ast":1,"blk":0,"dreb":3,"fg3_pct":0.0,"fg3a":0,"fg3m":0,"fg_pct":75.0,"fga":4,"fgm":3,"ft_pct":100.0,"fta":4,"ftm":4,"game":{"id":455103,"date":"2021-08-10T00:00:00.000Z","home_team_id":11,"home_team_score":111,"period":0,"postseason":false,"season":2021,"status":"Final","time":"","visitor_team_id":9,"visitor_team_score":91},"min":"13:48","oreb":3,"pf":1,"player":{"id":666517,"first_name":"Tyler","height_feet":null,"height_inches":null,"last_name":"Cook","position":"C","team_id":5,"weight_pounds":null},"pts":10,"reb":6,"stl":0,"team":{"id":9,"abbreviation":"DET","city":"Detroit","conference":"East","division":"Central","full_name":"Detroit Pistons","name":"Pistons"},"turnover":1},{"id":7065958,"ast":2,"blk":1,"dreb":3,"fg3_pct":0.0,"fg3a":3,"fg3m":0,"fg_pct":37.5,"fga":8,"fgm":3,"ft_pct":50.0,"fta":2,"ftm":1,"game":{"id":455103,"date":"2021-08-10T00:00:00.000Z","home_team_id":11,"home_team_score":111,"period":0,"postseason":false,"season":2021,"status":"Final","time":"","visitor_team_id":9,"visitor_team_score":91},"min":"24:28","oreb":2,"pf":4,"player":{"id":666543,"first_name":"Sekou","height_feet":null,"height_inches":null,"last_name":"Doumbouya","position":"F","team_id":14,"weight_pounds":null},"pts":7,"reb":5,"stl":1,"team":{"id":9,"abbreviation":"DET","city":"Detroit","conference":"East","division":"Central","full_name":"Detroit Pistons","name":"Pistons"},"turnover":1},{"id":7065959,"ast":2,"blk":1,"dreb":4,"fg3_pct":44.4,"fg3a":9,"fg3m":4,"fg_pct":44.4,"fga":18,"fgm":8,"ft_pct":0.0,"fta":0,"ftm":0,
```

an extract for matchs:

```
{"data":[{"id":455107,"date":"2021-08-10T00:00:00.000Z","home_team":{"id":12,"abbreviation":"IND","city":"Indiana","conference":"East","division":"Central","full_name":"Indiana Pacers","name":"Pacers"},"home_team_score":83,"period":0,"postseason":false,"season":2021,"status":"Final","time":"","visitor_team":{"id":1,"abbreviation":"ATL","city":"Atlanta","conference":"East","division":"Southeast","full_name":"Atlanta Hawks","name":"Hawks"},"visitor_team_score":84},{"id":473359,"date":"2021-10-04T00:00:00.000Z","home_team":{"id":16,"abbreviation":"MIA","city":"Miami","conference":"East","division":"Southeast","full_name":"Miami Heat","name":"Heat"},"home_team_score":125,"period":4,"postseason":false,"season":2021,"status":"Final","time":"","visitor_team":{"id":1,"abbreviation":"ATL","city":"Atlanta","conference":"East","division":"Southeast","full_name":"Atlanta Hawks","name":"Hawks"},"visitor_team_score":99}
```

Comment: [error]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[error]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[error]         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
error] stack trace is suppressed; run last Compile / run for the full output

Comment: could you add an example of the json that you are using as an input and also the full error message that you are getting? based on [UNRESOLVED_COLUMN.WITH_SUGGESTION](https://docs.databricks.com/error-messages/unresolved-column-error-class.html) looks like you are trying to work with a column that doesn't have that name. I can see that in val `teamNamesColumn` you used `.as("team_names")` and in the next line you are trying to use `col("team_names")` without having any reference to the previous val declared

Comment: i write the entirly error on my main post

Comment: please edit your post using the corresponding formatting to show the `json`s. looks like you don't have a field `team_names`. you only created that column in the line `val teamNamesColumn = lit(teamNames.mkString(",")).as("team_names")` and then you didn't added or use it anywhere else.